# Why is the SS(A|B) larger than SS(A) in anova analysis

Tags: r, anova

```
**Analysis 1**
Code: anova(lm(y~A+B))
Result: 
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
          A   1  40.58  40.583  214.11 < 2.2e-16 ***
          B   4 171.31  42.829  225.96 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals       1994 377.94   0.190

**Analysis 2**
Code: anova(lm(y~B+A))
Result: 
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
          B    4  87.10  21.774  114.88 < 2.2e-16 ***
          A    1 124.80 124.800  658.43 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals        1994 377.94   0.190
```

From analysis 1, SS(A) = 40.58, while from analysis 2, SS(A|B) = 124.80, which is larger than SS(A) from analysis 1. If I want to evaluate the effect of A after excluding the effect of B, I should use analysis 2. However, in analysis 2, I get a larger SS(A|B) and F value than SS(A) and F value obtained from analysis 1. From my understanding, SS(A|B) should always be smaller than SS(A) since the variance accounted by B has been taken away. This leads to the conclusion that after accounting for the effect of B, I get a more significant A effect, which makes me confused.

Comment: A and B are not independent!

Comment: @MichaelM, you are welcome to edit my answer to explain why this must be the case. I think it would make for a better answer and I am not confident in my intuition to do it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I screwed around in R and managed to get a similar phenomenon with the following code.

```
set.seed(0)
X = list()
X$a = rnorm(50)
X$y = rnorm(50) 
X$b = with(X, 10*a + y) + rnorm(50)
anova(lm(y~a+b, X))
anova(lm(y~b+a, X))
X$lp = with(X, b - 10*a)
pairs(X)
```

Here's my read. There's one scenario in which A and B are correlated and correcting for B leaves less association between A and y. This is often taught and it seems to be what you had in mind. But, there's another possible scenario which seems to be applicable here: what if A and B are not very useful individually, but are very useful jointly? Then whatever gets added to the model second gives a big leap in the explanatory power of the model. You can see in the last line of code that the linear predictor $b-10a$ (`lp`) explains $y$ far better than $a$ or $b$ alone.

As Michael M notes, this example does not leave $a$ and $b$ dependent.

Comment: Interestingly, the causal graph implied by this example has y and a causing b, not and and b causing y.

Comment: Is that possible to plot a Venn graph to illustrate this? Just as what was did in figure 2 from this article https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1860&context=jmasm

Comment: The intuition of this question is to examine the effect of b while controlling the effect of covariate a. Can I understand the big leap in value of SS(b|a) as the true effect of b on y? [In my case, a and b are not that highly correlated]

Comment: Causal interpretation is difficult, but it seems like there's a clear signal in your data that both A and B contain useful signal for predicting Y. If I were to draw a diagram to represent partitioning of variance, I would show two different panels. Both would have the total variance of Y as the full area. Both would show, within that, the variance explained by a linear model containing A and B. Up to that point, both panels would look the same. But within the inside compartment, the left panel would show a smaller area for the variance explained by a linear model containing only A.

Comment: ... the right would show the variance explained by a linear model containing only B.